# Writing to Google Cloud Storage - Testing Locally

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm testing my Google App Engine app locally in Windows. I want to be able to save my data to Google Cloud Storage like so:

```
file_put_contents('gs://my_folder/filename.json', $jsonFile);
```

It works great while running live on Google App Engine. But when I test it locally, it appears to run fine (no errors) but I don't know where it's saving the file. I thought I'd find it in the local admin console in my browser, but no luck.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I just tested getting the file from the same location using 'file_get_contents' and it worked! But isn't there somewhere I can go to see all my files in my 'localhost' cloud storage??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Admin console and then to the "Datastore Viewer".

Then select the Entity Kind "`_GsFileInfo_`" and your gs files will be displayed.

```
http://localhost:8000/datastore?kind=__BlobInfo__
```

Stack won't let me make a link to localhost, but it's something like the above.

Comment: Here's the actual link if you want to go straight there: http://localhost:8000/datastore?kind=__GsFileInfo__